# Search for a string that start with a wildcard in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, wildcard, kibana, x509certificate

I am building a kibana dashboard that displays information about `X509 certificates`. I would like to build a pie chart of certificates that contain a wildcard in their `CN` or `SAN` attributes, but I cannot find a query syntax that works.

To match a string like `subject.cn: "*.example.net"`, I tried the following kibana queries:

```
subject.cn:/\*./
subject.cn:/^\*./
subject.cn:\*\.
subject.cn:\*.
subject.cn:*.
```

Could someone point me to the proper syntax? Is this even something ES/Lucene supports?

Comment: how is "*.example.net" stored in the field? if analysed you may have lost the asterisk and periods and just be storing "example" and "net" as two terms. Which query function are you using?  e.g. query_string, match, etc.?

Comment: Here's an example cert with the subject.cn hilighted on line 27 https://linuxwall.info/p/NsrE#L27 As you can see, the wildcard is still present.

Comment: this doesn't show what mapping you've used - have you used the default mapping?

Comment: No, the mapping has been updated to support raw fields. Here it is: https://linuxwall.info/p/yRzh#L66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Olly's answer, I was able to find a solution that works. Once the `raw` fields defined, the trick is to escape the wildcard to treat it as a character, and to surround it with unescape wildcards, to accept surrounding characters:

```
ca:false AND (subject.cn.raw:*\** OR x509v3Extensions.subjectAlternativeName.raw:*\**)
```

Answer (score 1):

Analysing `*.example.net` with the **standard analyser** will give you a single term of `example.net` - i.e. the asterisk and first "." have been stripped.

Using **not_analyzed** will store the complete field `*.example.net` (as expected!)

If the wildcard is always at the beginning of the CN name then using a simple prefix query will work (I've simplified the field name):

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/mytest/certificates/_search?pretty' -d '{
 "query": {
    "prefix": { "cn.raw":"*"}
   }
 }'
```

However if you want to search against different levels of the domain name you'll need to change the analyser you're using.

E.g. use the [pattern analyser](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html) and define "." as your delimiter or possibly create a custom analyzer that calls the [path hierarchy tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html) - it's going to depend on how user's want to search your data.